# Is "What We Do in the Shadows" referenced in "Thor: Ragnarok"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, thor-ragnarok, what-we-do-in-the-shadows

In [Thor: Ragnarok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok), when Thor was preparing to fight the Grandmaster's champion, Korg suggested to Thor to use a trident-like wooden fork:

> **Korg:** Thor, wanna use a big wooden fork?
>   **Thor:** No.
>   **Korg:** Yeah, not really useful. Unless you're fighting off ***three vampires that were huddled together***.

That really struck my mind, having just watched [What We Do in the Shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_We_Do_in_the_Shadows) the other day. What We Do in the Shadows, which is also directed by and starred [Taika Waititi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taika_Waititi), is a mockumentary about three vampires.

Furthermore:

- More than 80% of the dialogue in Thor: Ragnarok was improvised, and since Korg is played by Waititi himself, he could've improvised that reference to his earlier film on set.
- Korg is a Kronan, so vampires being an earthian myth, is not likely to be mentioned by him unless it is used as an obvious reference.

So, are the three vampires mentioned by Korg a reference to the three vampires in What We Do in the Shadows? Can anyone prove/disprove my claim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

Although it is not mentioned by any of the cast members or even Waititi himself, several articles have been published on the potential Easter Egg.

According to [Inverse](https://www.inverse.com/article/38082-thor-ragnarok-easter-egg-what-we-do-in-the-shadows-taika-waititi)

> One of Korg’s friendly but not helpful suggestions for a weapon is a forked wooden spear (no, not a trident) that Thor dismisses quickly. Unphased, Korg admits something like, “Yeah, not very useful unless you’re up against three vampires all huddled up, eh?” The reference is a bit obtuse, but considering it’s Waititi himself speaking the line, it’s likely a nod to What We Do in the Shadows.
>
> The line itself might have been improvised by Waititi, but we can’t help but wonder: How would an alien Kronan even know what a vampire is? Does that low-key confirm that vampires are real in the MCU, and they’ve fought in the arena before? In the Taikaverse maybe, but perhaps not in the canon Marvel Cinematic Universe. At least not until Blade shows up.

According to the [Comic Book](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/11/05/thor-ragnarok-taika-waititi-what-we-do-in-the-shadows-stuart/)

> Thor: Ragnarok might contain plenty of surprise celebrity cameos and Marvel Comics Easter eggs, but it also has a unique connection to one of Taika Waititi's past film.

According to [Movie Pilot](https://moviepilot.com/p/what-we-do-in-shadows-thor-easter-egg-sequel/4436874)

> To those unfamiliar with Waititi’s previous work, this might have seemed like a general vampire joke — but longtime fans recognized this as a reference to his 2014 horror comedy mockumentary centered around three vampires living in New Zealand.